# Structured data blog post vs review

Tags: seo, microdata, schema.org, structured-data

I have a blog on my website. I write articles on it and product reviews.

When using structured data, how should I markup the blog post and review? I am currently using:

```
http://schema.org/BlogPosting
```

When I do a write up on a product review, should I still use BlogPosting or should I use something else for the review?

It is a review on clothes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anwser edited:

On second thought. You don't have to choose. You can use `BlogPosting` and in the about field you use `Review` directly or choose `Product` and use its review field.

```
<article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <h1 itemprop="name headline">some clothing review</h1>
  <p>
    <time datetime="2015-03-26T10:43:39Z" itemprop="datePublished">26 Mar 2015</time>
  </p>
  <img itemprop="image" src="some_clothing_item.jpg" alt="some clothing item" />
  <div itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <span itemprop="brand">ACME</span>
      <span itemprop="name">some clothing item</span>

      <span itemprop="description">description here...</span>
      <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
           <span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
           <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span> 
           </span> stars stars by <span itemprop="author">me</span>
           <div itemprop="reviewBody">
              <p>a very stylish .....</p>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Original anwser:
Is [schema.org/Review](http://schema.org/Review) what you are looking for?

Comment: It might be. I am looking at the bigger picture, which is a blog. Should I then mark the post as a review, or stick to marking it as a blog post?

Comment: @Brendan-Vogt using Review gives you a lot more detail in the ItemReviewed field you can specifiy the type and it's fields. This gives a lot more detail than just Blogposting.
And google has specific support for schema.org/Review see https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews?hl=en&rd=1

Comment: Ok now that you have 3 schemas in one, what will your result look like in the SERP? Will it display the result as a blog post or review?

Answer (score 1):

You could use both types, [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) and [`Review`](http://schema.org/Review).

That’s perfectly fine in RDFa and JSON-LD. In Microdata, it’s allowed to use multiple types, too, but it’s (strictly speaking) not allowed to use properties that aren’t defined for all these types; many ignore this restriction, though (and I think Schema.org intends to explicitly allow this for their vocabulary).

(A less ideal solution for Microdata is to use the [`additionalType`](http://schema.org/additionalType) property, but that doesn’t allow you to use the properties from this additional type.)

Answer (score 0):

The first question you should answer is why. Why do you want to use structured data? What do you want to achieve with it?

If you want to get rich snippets displayed for your blog in SERPs, so you should use only limited set of types and properties. They are:

**for blog posts**: only rating of a certain article;

**shown rich snippet**: rating stars and amount of votes

- http://schema.org/AggregateRating

**for closes reviews**: rating, product and offer data;

**shown rich snippets**: product price, availability, rating stars and amount of votes

- http://schema.org/Review

  - http://schema.org/Product
  - http://schema.org/Offer
  - http://schema.org/AggregateRating